# How can add php json file to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to integrate the const data variable into the php file externally. What code does it do? I am changing the data on my php page to json format, but how do I pull it into the javascript page?

User.js File:

```
const data = {users: [
{
  id: 1,
  fullName: 'Galen Slixby',
  company: 'Yotz PVT LTD',
  role: 'editor',
  username: 'gslixby0',
  country: 'El Salvador',
  contact: '(479) 232-9151',
  email: 'gslixby0@abc.net.au',
  currentPlan: 'enterprise',
  status: 'inactive',
  avatar: '',
},
```

],
}

User.php file:

```
$response = []; $response['users']=[]; foreach($firmalar as $firma){ $response['data'][] = [
  "avatar"=>"",
  'id'=> $firma['id'],
  'responsive_id' => '',
  'full_name'=> $firma['firma_adi'],
  'email'=> $firma['firma_mail'],
  'role'=> $firma['firma_sektor'],
  'current_plan'=> $firma['firma_telefon'],
  'status'=> $firma['firma_tehlike']


]; }   echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: Yes I'm trying it right now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey I have another question for fetch api.  When I pull the data with the api, I cannot create a const with that data.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC the structure you're aiming for require to map it in PHP.
So you have an object with one element `users` and value - array of objects (potentially users). Keeping that in mind you should have same thing in PHP before encoding.

```
<?php

    $json = new stdClass();
    $json->users = [];
     
    $firmalar = [
        [
           'id' => 1,     
           'firma_adi' => 'firma_adi',     
           'firma_mail' => 'firma_mail',
           'firma_sektor' => 'firma_sektor',
           'firma_telefon' => 'firma_telefon',
           'firma_tehlike' => 'firma_tehlike',
        ],     
    ];
     
    foreach($firmalar as $firma)
    { 
        $user = new stdClass();
        $user->avatar = "";
        $user->id = $firma['id'];
        $user->responsive_id = '';
        $user->full_name = $firma['firma_adi'];
        $user->email = $firma['firma_mail'];
        $user->role = $firma['firma_sektor'];
        $user->current_plan = $firma['firma_telefon'];
        $user->status = $firma['firma_tehlike'];
        
        $json->users[] = $user;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);

    //or if you want that data available in your js file simply generate valid JS statement for assigning produced json to (in you case) constant BEFORE loading the JS file
    echo 'const data =\''.json_encode($json).'\'';
```

Please follow [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) documentation for more details on usage.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I know that the values will be equal. I presented here only for show. I can Json.encode (). But my problem here is about how to fetch the json file into the javascript file.

Comment: You need to produce a string in php that could be later evaluated as valid JS constant (in your case):
<?php echo 'const data =\''.json_encode($json).'\''; ?>
The above should happen before you load the JS file in order be available there.

Answer (score 0):

response()->json($result); is the solution!